# Reactive default webpage scrolling - Zoom and brush for victorycharts

Tags: reactjs, zooming, brush, victory-charts

I have been working with victorycharts and it has been very helpful. I have a working chart using the https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/guides/brush-and-zoom/ and the example of having a scatter plot with brush and zoom has been very helpful. I was wondering if there was a way to have the default window scrolling active instead of zooming-on-scroll. I tried using the built in function to deactivate the zoom on scroll, but that just creates a dead zone where nothing happens when the user scrolls.

In summary, I currently have a scatterplot and a brush window that has a mini scatterplot inside of it. Currently I have two options when I scroll inside of the main scatterplot - it either zooms in to a specific part, or nothing happens. What I want is for the scrolling to ignore the scatterplot and be able to scroll inside of the page like normal.